# Why Android system tries to serialize a View?

Tags: android, android-layout, serialization, android-fragments

I have a custom `View` and sometimes I get reported crashes for:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.myapp.views.MyCustomView
```

For few `Fragments`I have declared a member of  this view for easier usage not having to use `findViewById` all the time. I've also tried to declare member views as `transient` to prevent this behavior.

Very to hard to post some code, because I have no idea why this is happening, but the basic architecture is following:

1. `Fragment` with xml layout
2. Create `MyCustomView` which is `FrameLayout` dynamically and add to that `Fragment`
3. Initiate `MyCustomView` pointer and pass to another `View` as member for usage

Also I've never got this crash myself, I get the crash report using `BugSense` crash library.

UPDATE: Somehow this is connected to my one data class which implements `Serializable`. I decompiled the package and the crash trace also shows is actually a data class:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.myapp.f.y)
```

And `MyCustomView`has a member of that object. So the `Serializable` object is being serialized and somehow `MyCustomView` tries to serialize itself too ?

UPDATE:

Crash count for avg 2k daily users is about 10 per day. Trace showing that when home pressed:

```
android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
```

system tries to serialize, could there be some threading issue that some operation or animation is still ongoing and thats causing system trying to serialize a `View` ?

UPDATE:

This seems to happen only with 2.x platform devices.

Comment: Can you post some code to show us what you have done?

Comment: "pass to another View as member for usage" How do you do that?

Comment: Just basic setter for members where my another View also being custom view having member of MyCustomView

Comment: have you figured out what's happening? I face a similar issue

Comment: No sorry, at the time we raised min API level so didn't need to worry about this anymore.